# Problem using aioboto3 to access AWS Cognito in FastAPI

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito, fastapi

Is it possible to access AWS Cognito using aioboto3 in a FastAPI application? Using this code:

```
session = aioboto3.Session()
async with session.client("cognito_idp", region_name=os.getenv("REGION")) as cognito_client:
response = await cognito_client.initiate_auth(
    ClientId=os.getenv("APP_CLIENT_ID"),
    AuthFlow="USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    AuthParameters={"USERNAME": username, "PASSWORD": password},
)
return response
```

I get an error message:

```
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"
```

If I code this up with just boto (not async):

```
client = boto3.client("cognito-idp", region_name=os.getenv("REGION"))
response = client.initiate_auth(
    ClientId=os.getenv("APP_CLIENT_ID"),
    AuthFlow="USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    AuthParameters={"USERNAME": username, "PASSWORD": password},
)
return response
```

I get the response I'm expecting. Any suggestions about how to fix this, or why it won't work would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: having the same issue, did you ever get this working?

Comment: I ended up running the boto3 calls in a thread

Comment: I just figured this out a little while ago, I had to pass a config `config=AioConfig(signature_version=UNSIGNED),` and then it works properly

Comment: What is the value of UNSIGNED?

Comment: Sorry missed your reply. It's not a value, it's a class `from botocore import UNSIGNED`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did actually figure that out looking at the source code for botocore. :)